# Unable to get result from querying a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I was working with a database in MySQL, where I have a table say ABC.

I want to query the database for a given search keyword, and display the output in a table. When I am querying with the following code, it is working fine:(Games Played 1 is a column name)

```
if($_POST['searchby'] == "Games Type"){
          $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM users_entity WHERE `Games Played 1' LIKE '%".$searchword."%'";
```

However, when I am trying to check whether the keyword is present in two columns, **Games Played 1 or Games Played 2**, it is not working. I am using the following code for that.

```
if($_POST['searchby'] == "Games Type"){
          $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM elgg_users_entity WHERE `Games Played 1` OR `Games Played 2` LIKE '%".$searchword."%'";
```

Can anyone suggest where I am doing wrong?? Also, when I run the webpage with the above code, it gives a warning as **"The MySQL server has gone away"**

Comment: You are missing the first condition: `Select * from table WHERE condition OR condition`. You have to use `'Games Played 1' LIKE 'SOMETHING' OR 'Games Played 2' LIKE 'SOMETHING'`. Run the final generated query outside php and see.

Comment: Thanks all, it is working fine now..

Comment: Also, it looks like you are vulnerable to SQL Injection. Take a look at [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be like this:

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM elgg_users_entity WHERE `Games Played 1` LIKE '%".$searchword."%' OR `Games Played 2` LIKE '%".$searchword."%'";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if($_POST['searchby'] == "Games Type"){
          $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM elgg_users_entity WHERE `Games Played 1` LIKE '%".$searchword."%' OR `Games Played 2` LIKE '%".$searchword."%'";
```

Answer (score 2):

**Errors**

1. Wrong `WHERE` condition.

---

**So final code is**

```
if($_POST['searchby'] == "Games Type"){
      $query_Recordset1 = "
      SELECT * 
      FROM elgg_users_entity 
      WHERE table_coumn1 
        LIKE '%$searchword%'  
      OR table_coumn2 
        LIKE '%$searchword%' ";
```

---

### For Your Information

> > **Don't use spaces between table column names(`Games Played 1`). Add it with `_`separated word. (Games_Played_1).**
> >
> > **Hence make it all small caps as best practices**

Comment: @Arnab if my answer helpful grateful by accepting it or Vote it. Thank you